# Is it normal that sync() from unistd.h takes multiple seconds

Tags: sd-card, filesystem

When a user performs some setup via a Web GUI, I'm calling `sync()` to ensure the setup changement is immediately saved to the SD Card. (I'm doing this because the user sometimes switches off the power after doing the setup task)

I'm working with raspbian. My SD Card is a 16GB Kingston Class 10 (industrial).

Calling the `sync()` system call (from `unistd.h`) will block normally about 1-2 seconds, but sometimes it can block up to >5 secs. IMHO: Between two calls of sync() I'm not writing more than 1MB to the persistent filesystem.

I've disabled a lot of logs. `/var/log`, `/run`, `/tmp` are `tempfs`

Is this normal that `sync()` blocks as this long? What can I do to reduce the consumed time by `sync()` ?

### Additional Info

I've checked the disk IO with `sudo iotop -o -a` for some minutes:

```
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
   95 be/3 root          0.00 B   1544.00 K  0.00 %  1.03 % [jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]
32254 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.63 % [kworker/u8:2]
 5975 be/4 root          0.00 B    528.00 K  0.00 %  0.32 % myapp.elf
```

Is syncing to SD Card really that slow?

Comment: I have never noticed a delay but only use the command from a shell.  The obvious answer is the time is due to writing the buffered data.  Are you confident that is not the reason?

Comment: calling `time sync`on the shell gives me also several seconds

Comment: I have just tried on a Pi freshly booted.  The first (shell) sync took 5 seconds, subsequent ones 5 to 6 milliseconds.  That is much faster than my laptop, 200-400 milliseconds.  My laptop has an older version of Linux, which might explain its comparative slowness.